# Multiple equal ifs should return different values from different methods (C#)?

Tags: c#, if-statement, return-value

I have some methods which use if conditions, like this:

```
string method1()
{
    bool x= Convert.ToBoolean(...);
    bool y= Convert.ToBoolean(...);

     if (x && y)
     {
         return " ";
     }

     if (!x && y)
     {
         return " ";
      }

      if (!y && x)
      {
          return " ";
      }

      if (!x && !y)
      {
          return "X";
      }

      return " ";
  }
```

Thats my first method, now I have a similiar one, which has the same checks and the same boolean values, but returns other strings (not space or X). Whats an elegeant approach to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post how you use this in your code. It looks like you need to redesign your application so you won't have to do this.

Comment: Really the only solution to making these conditional tests reusable is to remove the code that performs the conditional test from the code that returns stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elegant approach is to refactor your code so that the boolean checks are in their own method that each of the other two methods can access, and then each method can return a string based on the result of the boolean check.

**EXAMPLE**

```
private int BinaryTruthTest(bool x, bool y)
{
   if(x && y)
   {
      return 3;
   }
   if(!x && y)
   {
      return 1;
   }
   if(!y && x)
   {
      return 2;
   }
   if(!x && !y)
   {
      return 0;
   }
}

string method1()
{
   bool x = Convert.ToBoolean(...);
   bool y = Convert.ToBoolean(...);

   int testResult = BinaryTruthTest(x, y);

   if(testResult==0)
   {
      return "X";
   }
   else
   {
      return " ";
   }
}
```

Comment: @grady I've provided an example.

Answer (score 4):

According to your code you only return "X" if both x and y are false. In that case every other combination should return " ". This could be shortened but I left it as is for readability.

```
method1("X", " ");
method1("OtherValue", " ");

string method1(string matchValue, string nonMatchValue)
{
    bool x= Convert.ToBoolean(...);
    bool y= Convert.ToBoolean(...);

      if (!x && !y)
      {
          return matchValue;
      }

      return nonMatchValue;
  }
```

Comment: That would work for the space case, but not for the case that each if returns something different.

Answer (score 2):

Why not pass the desired return values as parameters to the method?

```
string method1(string returnVal1, string returnVal2)
{
    bool x= Convert.ToBoolean(...);
    bool y= Convert.ToBoolean(...);

    if (x && y)
    {
        return returnVal1;
    }

    if (!x && y)
    {
        return returnVal1;
    }

    if (!y && x)
    {
        return returnVal1;
    }

    if (!x && !y)
    {
        return returnVal2;
    }

    return returnVal1;
}
```

Comment: it may not be the case that OP is only returning 1 of 2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want a generic version of that method where only the results change, you could pass the result as a 2-dimension array....

```
string method1(string[][] result) {
   bool x= Convert.ToBoolean(...);
   bool y= Convert.ToBoolean(...);
   int u = (x ? 1 : 0);
   int v = (y ? 1 : 0);
   return result[u][v];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the real-world problem, but I suspect you need a new class that can be reused anywhere:

```
class DecisionMaker
{
    string _both;
    string _notX;
    string _notY;
    string _neither;
    string _default;

    public DecisionMaker(string both, string notX, string notY, string neither, string defaultVal)
    {
        _both = both;
        _notX = notX;
        _notY = notY;
        _neither = neither;
        _default = defaultVal;
    }

    public string Method1(bool x, bool y)
    {
        if (x && y)
            return _both;

        if (!x && y)
            return _notX;

        if (!y && x)
            return _notY;

        if (!x && !y)
            return _neither;

        return _default;
    }
}
```

Or optionally, you can have the Convert.ToBoolean(...) stuff inside Method1 and make Method1 have no parameters. Or you could create a DecisionMakerBase abstract class with protected abstract methods that allow you to only change what functionality you need to change. It really depends on your scenario.

Comment: What happens if OP needs/wants to perform the same conditional analysis but needs to return ints instead of strings? OP will end up doing a copy/paste of this code which is BAD.

Comment: @Phil that would be fine, but you'd still have pretty tight coupling between the conditions and return values. What happens if/when there's a third condition, e.g. x,y, and z rather than just x and y?

Comment: @Brian It really depends on the actual real world problem, but I would be willing to bet we need a new class, not a method. We just don't know enough about the problem.

Comment: @Brian Besides, looking at your code, all you've done is converted bools to integers. Instead of if (x && y) you now have if (testResult == 0). method1 is still making the decision.

Comment: @Phil My code allows for easy reuse of the conditional test in other methods, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: @Brian, Right, that's what we have both given him. He is able to reuse the logic and change the return values... The return values are not coupled to the boolean logic. Regardless, I made an edit that probably nullifies this whole discussion.

Comment: @Phil I think you missed my point almost entirely, as your code still has the testing being done in Method1 and returning strings as a result. It may work for OP but it's very tightly coupled and not a very elegant solution. Honestly most of the solutions for this question (mine included) will probably work but are not the most elegant from a software design perspective. Sorry if it seems I picked on yours - it was just the first one I came upon after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want method two to return four different values for the four different cases then you could do:

```
string method1(string[] values)
{
if (x && y)
 {
     return values[0];
 }

 if (!x && y)
 {
     return values[1];
  }

  if (!y && x)
  {
      return values[2];
  }

  if (!x && !y)
  {
      return values[3];
  }
```

}

However that is not very pretty.
What is the use of this method in your application?